# Keepalived multiple condition TCP_CHECK

Tags: keepalive

I have few web servers under two keepalived servers, and to check the health of a real web server I use this fragment of keepalived configuration

```
      TCP_CHECK                 # healthchecker : HTTP_GET|SSL_GET|TCP_CHECK|SMTP_CHECK|MISC_CHECK
      {
         connect_timeout 3              # Timeout connection, sec
         nb_get_retry 3         # number of get retry
         delay_before_retry 3
         connect_port 80
         }
```

But besides apache I also need to check if mongos is running on that server, and if one of this to applications is not ok I need to pull out the server from the list of real servers? So how can I add logical expressions in keepalived's config.

Comment: I think it is more likely that you find an answer to this question on ServerFault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MISC_CHECK:

```
MISC_CHECK {
   misc_path "/etc/keepalived/servicecheck.sh"
}
```

Where /etc/keepalived/servicecheck.sh is a shell script that does all of the useful checking for you:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Check if mongo is running
mongo --eval "db.stats()"
RESULT=$?   # returns 0 if mongo eval succeeds

if [ $RESULT -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "mongodb not running"
    exit 1
else
    echo "mongodb running!"
fi

# Check if apache is running
ps auxw | grep apache2 | grep -v grep > /dev/null

if [ $? != 0 ]
then
        exit 1
fi
```

This is just an example. You can build any amount of logic in your script. Any return status of 1 will cause keepalived to bring the server out of service.